# ggplot2 is mutating/transforming size variables -- how to get back original data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 seems to mutating/transforming size variables.

Consider the following

```
require(ggplot2); require(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), size = runif(100))
p.out <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size = size)) + geom_point()
p.data <- p.out %>% layer_data %>% arrange(x)
d2 <- d %>% arrange(x)
head(d2)
             x           y      size
## 1 -2.345698 -0.50247778 0.7757949
## 2 -2.180040 -0.31611833 0.3802893
## 3 -1.806031 -0.37723765 0.2547007
## 4 -1.629093 -1.65010093 0.2722072
## 5 -1.448205  0.08005964 0.1999333
## 6 -1.390701 -1.12376279 0.5117742

p.data %>% select(size, x, y) %>% head

##       size         x           y
## 1 5.407443 -2.345698 -0.50247778
## 2 4.084550 -2.180040 -0.31611833
## 3 3.523348 -1.806031 -0.37723765
## 4 3.608829 -1.629093 -1.65010093
## 5 3.234916 -1.448205  0.08005964
## 6 4.579018 -1.390701 -1.12376279
```

x and y seem to match the original data

```
lm(y ~ x, p.data)


## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = p.data)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            x  
##     0.03715     -0.02608  

lm(y ~ x, d)

## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            x  
##     0.03715     -0.02608
```

But the size variable seems to mutated/transformed somehow

```
cor(p.data$size, d2$size)
## [1] 0.9783827

lm(y ~ x, data = d, weights = size)

## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d, weights = size)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            x  
##    -0.02586     -0.11537  

lm(y ~ x, p.data, weights = size)

## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x, data = p.data, weights = size)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)            x  
##     0.009372    -0.065445
```

ggplot2 seems to be producing the correct plot when I use the original data, but I can't seem to reproduce the plot from `layer_data()` or from `ggplot_build()`. How can I transform the `size` variable in `p.data` to get back the original size variable?

Comment: Nice find. How about `p.out$data`?

Comment: Oh. good call! I didn't know about `p.out$data`.. `p.out$data` gives me the actual data as `cor(p.out.data$size, d2$size)` is equal to 1 (when I arrange everything by x), but `cor(p.out.data$size, p.data$size)` is equal to 0.978 as above. I'm not sure what's going on here. I've tried the above a few ways and I don't think there's an error in my code. In the end, p.out$data gives me what I want. Feel free to answer and I'll accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something interesting going on, perhaps someone more intimately familiar with ggplot2 can chip in. In the mean time, try calling the data from the ggplot object directly using `p.out$data`.

Comment: One more quick comment: The advantage of layer_data and and ggplot_build is they changed the names to "x", "y", "size", etc. `p.out$data` will use the default names given by the user and then one must use `p.out$mapping` to figure out which variables correspond to to the x and y axes, etc.